# Apache Superset - Calculate Period average difference between different time periods in a time series table

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

We are trying to build a superset chart to show attendance distribution for students and show the difference in average attendance % of a student from current week to last week.

We have created global time range filters to define the Current period and Previous period time ranges, which are applied to different charts based on fiter scoping settings.

With this approach we are able to use a time-series table to plot out the period average, difference in time lag and sparkline trend individually, however is there a way we get the difference to indicate the difference between the period average of the current period and the period average from the previous period.

Please see the attached diagram for a representation of the requirement.

[Requirement Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWbxK.png)

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if you require anymore details.